# How might I extract the number from a number + unit of measure string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

If I have this string

```
str = "22px";
```

How do I extract just the number 22? Thanks.

Comment: Could you say more of what you want? Do you want to find all digits up until the first non-digit character? Or do you want to find everything up until "px"? Or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try str.match(/\d+/);

Comment: A better solution than mine... I would of suggested this route if I was up to stuff on my reg expressions...

Comment: Thanks, wheres the best place to learn reg expressions for javascript?

Comment: A pretty good site is regular-expressions.info. It also has a javascript regex tester. http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 5):

If you want an actual number, you should try parseInt(). It will take care of taking off the 'px' for you.

```
str = "22px";

num = parseInt(str, 10); // pass in the radix for safety :)

assert(num === 22);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a regex that splits the value from the unit. It also works with negative values and decimal numbers:

```
str.match(/(-?[\d.]+)([a-z%]*)/)
```

Regex explained:

- `(-?[\d.]+)` .. Grabs an optional "-" followed by digits or dots
- `([a-z%]*)` .. Finds all letters or % signs that directly follow the number

Here's a sample function that returns the specific parts:

```js
function parseVal(str) {
    res = str.match(/(-?[\d.]+)([a-z%]*)/);
    return {
        val: parseFloat(res[1]),
        unit: res[2]
    }
}

parseVal( '12px' )               // { val: 12, unit: 'px' }
parseVal( '-20.5%' )             // { val: -20.5, unit: '%' }
parseVal( '22.75em' )            // { val: 22.75, unit: 'em' }
parseVal( '1234' )               // { val: 1234, unit: '' }
parseVal( 'margin-top: -50px;' ) // { val: -50, unit: 'px' }
```

The last example above shows how "smart" the regex is: It ignores all non-numeric values at the beginning and excess characters at the end - i.e., `margin-top:`  and `;` are stripped off

**Note**

The regex is quite simple. When it receives invalid values it will return unexpected results:

```js
parseVal("...")           // { val: NaN, unit: "" }
parseVal("2.3.4.5pxpxpx") // { val: 2.3, unit: "pxpxpx" }
parseVal("dummy")         // TypeError!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
parseInt("22px");
```

Comment: This is the cleanest and fastest solution. If dealing with float values like `12.5em`, then use `parseFloat(str)`. NOTE: This solution also works with negative values, like `-22px` (as in "margin-top: -22px")

Answer (score -1):

```
"22px".substring(0,2); // returns "22"
```

But this only works if the number has always 2 digits.

Comment: this answer... seriously... :D

Answer (score -2):

I think you can just go `str.substring(0, 2)`.