# Java Script - Extract number from string

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How might I extract the number from a number + unit of measure string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849149/how-might-i-extract-the-number-from-a-number-unit-of-measure-string-using-java)

How to extract number from string like this in JS.
String: "Some_text_123_text" -> 123

Comment: show your implementations first

Comment: Which number. The first one, the last one or all digits concatenated?

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want...

Answer (score 5):

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CGnUz/32/)

```
var s = "Some_text_123_text";
var index = s.match(/\d+/);
document.writeln(index);​
```

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky- ya but its working in jasfiddle..updated now

Comment: it sure works but thats not why i said it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var string = "Some_text_123_text";
var find = string.split("_");
for(var i = 0; i < find.length ; i ++){
 if(!isNaN(Number(find[i]))){
  var num = find[i];
 }
}

alert(num);
```

Comment: +1 this will also extract `-123` from `around_-123_minutes`

Comment: oh good didn't tryed with negatives, did you checked with 0.5?

Comment: Oh, sorry, this will only extract positive values.

Comment: yep :P it was just for fun :D

Comment: You could change this to `find[i] == find[i]`. Evaluates true for anything but `NaN`s (which are _not_ numbers :-) )

Comment: Sorry again - `find[i] == find[i]` will perform string comparison

Comment: my code is your code man, edit if you want np!

Answer (score 0):

try this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wXNDu/)

```
var str = "Some_text_123_text";
var patt1 = /[0-9]/g;
var arr= str.match(patt1);
var myval = arr.join("");
```

Comment: Why are you using the `g`lobal flag?

Comment: why are you using `[0-9]` instead of `\d`?

Comment: `myval` is still a string, albeit numeric.

Comment: @jan dvorak if I don't use global than I get only 1

Comment: @Jan-Stefan Janetzky I am not expert on regular expression, what I know I suggested